# Global pagination settings for Rest

Tags: yii2

How can I set defaultPageSize and pageSizeLimit globally in an Yii2 application? Docs does not seem to have this information, and all solutions on SO are controller-based.

Preferably in main.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [di container](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html#practical-usage)
just plop this in your bootstrap file

```
Yii::$container->set('yii\data\Pagination', ['pageSize' => 150]);
```